# "You are friend with..."

Tags: idioms, synonyms

In this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/203843/89027%5C) I provided a sample sentence:

> You are friend with Toby.

and as a result I received a comment from @JasonBassford:

> *Both of your example sentences are ungrammatical. You can't be *friend with* someone. You can be ***a*** friend **of** someone or you can *be **friendly with*** someone.*

Now, I tend to trust JasonBassford (as a result of seeing hos posts here on ELL), but a dilemma remains.

---

From my point of view, **friendship** and **friendliness** do not convey the same meaning.

I can be "friendly" with a dog or with some foreigner on the street, but that will not make us friends. Friendship (from my point of view) is much deeper and much more complex than friendliness.

So, to be explicit: is there another way to express friendship? I feel that something is missing, but I am not sure what that is.

As one alternative, I think about "to be friends with" (friend + s = plural):

> You are friend**s** with Toby.

but I cannot decide if it is fine / idiomatic, or if there is something else missing.

Comment: I don't know about other dialects, but in British English, we can use **friendly with** to talk about a relationship of friendship. I was friendly to a nice cat I saw in the street; I am friendly with Mary Smith; we have known each other since childhood. Jason Bassford's comment accords with this.

Comment: Hmmm... That is interesting. However, I prefer to be as non-ambiguous as possible, and as you describe it, "to be friendly with" has some potential to transmit incorrect information (compared to the intention).

Comment: Ambiguity? **Friendly to** is different from **friendly with**.

Comment: You could also say *You are Toby's friend.* In fact, that's probably the most idiomatic. (Additionally note that *friendship* implies *friendliness*, although not the reverse.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: "although not the reverse" - that is exactly why I asked this question :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I did not notice the different preposition: **to** vs **with**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do "friend of" and "friend with" have the same meaning?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/do-friend-of-and-friend-with-have-the-same-meaning)

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this is the preposition 'with'.

How many people are being talked about, one or two?

**You** are friends *with* **Toby**.

You are Toby's friend.  Toby is your friend.  Two friends.

It's not idiomatic, but rather the correct agreement.